# LINQ query with group by and ascending ordering not working

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a class Ingredients which has a property `Items` of the type `List<Ingredient>`.
In one of my pages I am using a GridView to display all the ingredients, grouped by first letter:

```xml
<Page.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Name="IngredientsViewSource" IsSourceGrouped="True" ItemsPath="Items"/>
</Page.Resources>
```

when the page is loaded, the CollectionViewSource's Source property is set like this:

```
this.IngredientsViewSource.Source = CurrentData.Ingredients.GroupedItems;
```

`GroupedItems` is a property of the Ingredients class, which takes the property `Items` and orders and groups everything in order to be ready to use:

```cs
public object GroupedItems
{
    get
    {
        if (this.Items != null)
        {
            return from IngredientIteration in this.Items
                       //orderby IngredientIteration.Name ascending
                       group IngredientIteration 
                           by IngredientIteration.FirstLetter
                           into IngredientGroup
                           //orderby IngredientGroup.Key ascending
                           select new { 
                                        FirstLetter = IngredientGroup.Key, 
                                        Items = IngredientGroup 
                                      };
        }
        else 
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    private set { }
}
```

this is working quite well. Now I would like to sort the result, because now the first letters' order is all messed up. However, when I remove the comment marks in front of the two `orderby` clauses, it get's totally weird. Leaving the orderby clauses like it is now results in correctly ordered groups, but only the first item per group is showed.
When I change ascending to descending, though, everything works as expected: groups are sorted descending, all items are shown, and the items are sorted descending inside each group.

This makes no sense to me, why is descending working but ascending not? Am I missing something here?

Comment: it looks to me that your `GroupedItems` would have the `Items` as an `IGrouping<...>`, I doubt that's not what you want. What's the actual data structure you want for each entry in `GroupedItems`?

Comment: I'd like to have a collection of these anonymous objects with each a string `FirstLetter` and a `List<Ingredient>` `Items`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although as what you described (descending works but ascending doesn't), it's so strange. Your query has nothing complicated, I would use the `method syntax` for it and it should work as you expected:

```
public object GroupedItems {
  get {
    if (this.Items != null)
    {
        return Items.OrderBy(item=>item.Name)
                    .GroupBy(item=>item.FirstLetter)
                    .OrderBy(g=>g.Key)
                    .Select(g=> new {
                               FirstLetter = g.Key,
                               Items = g.ToList()
                            }).ToList();
    }
    else  {
        return null;
    }
  }
  private set { }
}
```